# Scroll one line HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a div with a scrollbar and would like to be able to scroll vertically one line at a time. Currently it skips some lines. If i have 5 lines, it will skip every other line and show the next.

Please see my current code at the following link. When you scroll, you will notice it skips one line. Need to be able to view all lines. One at a time.

https://jsfiddle.net/vishism/fx8r15up/

My current CSS

```
#notesDiv {
line-height: 20px;
height: 23px;
overflow-y: scroll;
border: 1px solid #D8E8EC;
padding-left: 9px;
}
```

I have tried a few things and could not get it to work. Any assistance will be appreciated.

Thanks.